# Is there a conflict between free will and samskaras (innate tendencies)?

Tags: karma, rebirth, samskara, free-will

According to the theory of Karma, we carry our qualities to the next life. There is a famous verse in the Upanishad that as a caterpillar reaches the end of a blade of grass, it curls and collects its body and then jumps to the next blade. Similarly, souls also collect their tendencies (samskaras) and go to the next life.

It is something like we start where we left off in the last life. For example, suppose a guy was a pious person in his previous life, in this life, he will be born into a family of devotees, where the environment will be conducive for him to study shastras and rekindle his innate tendencies.

However, we frequently see in our societies that persons who are very successful and well-placed are doing terribly bad karma. Gurus say that this person is successful because he did good karma in his previous life. In this life, he is doing terrible things because of his free will, and he will get the fruits of this bad karma in the next life.

Now, the question is if the person really did good karma in the previous birth, then his samskaras should compel him to do good in this life also. A pious person in the last life should do pious things in this life also due to his samskaras. If you say it is free will, then you have to admit free will is stronger than sanskaras. If samskaras are weak, then the theory of karma will break down. How to resolve this conflict between samskara and free will?

Comment: Everywhere in nature we see the effect being intertwined with its cause , so is the (irreversible) effect of prarabdha karma (that which has to be reaped in this life),  generated by a cause done in the past.A motive (sankalpa) is always the reason for new cause.So the context is narrowed down to kriyamana karma .(new causes to be generated), Certainly, it would be influenced by  samskaras in stock , But If  a person is an absolute victim of this influence only (determinism),  then shaastras are redundant(useless).

Comment: as they cannot be adhered to..It is because a power of discrimination bestowed on humans , laws/shaastras apply. (as ,one can has a choice to discriminate between law and the samskaras.) Eventually one can either elevate to divine existence by viveka(discrimination,) or demote to lower existence ..Here all uncertainty is due to cause-effect relationship spanning across lives..In this case the pious person could be a novice/oblivious of shaastras so subscribes to a wrong influence (by power of circumstance) against his/her samskaras creating bad motive